# what is the proper way to set up an if statement to handle document.getElementsByClassName("class_name") undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var prev = document.getElementsByClassName("swiper-slide swiper-slide-prev");
var next = document.getElementsByClassName("swiper-slide swiper-slide-next");

alert(prev[0].className===undefined);
```

For example:

So where I have the alert.  What gets returned when `document.getElementsByClassName("swiper-slide swiper-slide-prev")` does not find a element with the class name `swiper-slide swiper-slide-prev`? How would you handle this in a if statement?

Comment: Can you please add your HTML code sample?

Comment: [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is your required logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `length` of the object to check if something was found by your selector.

```js
var prev = document.getElementsByClassName("swiper-slide swiper-slide-prev");
var next = document.getElementsByClassName("swiper-slide swiper-slide-next");

if( !prev.length ) {
    alert("no prev");
}

if( !next.length ) {
    alert("no next");
}
```

```html
<div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-next"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much eisbehr

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByClassName returns an array of found elements. If non was found it is empty.

so you can just check `if(prev.length === 0)`

Btw. you can easily try this one out in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

The getElementsByClassName return an **ARRAY** and you can know if you have an element with the length of the array. Here is an example:

```
var prev = document.getElementsByClassName("swiper-slide swiper-slide-prev");
var next = document.getElementsByClassName("swiper-slide swiper-slide-next");

if(prev.length > 0 ){
   alert(prev[0].className);
}
```

Obviously this element have a class name because you take it with the by the class name.

I hope that this helps you!